# How to redirect a specific user from multiple websites?

Tags: php, redirect

I have a few websites that collectively make up a user experience for a (variable) timed period. Once the user has completed the experience I want to be able to redirect them to a specific page if they try to return to any of the sites. I thought a session might be possible, but this wouldn't work across multiple sites? Is it is easier, and if so how would I go about, obtaining the users IP, and then redirecting them?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` gives you the client IP.

Comment: So when I want to implement it I can say $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = Foo. And then on each site do a redirect if $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = Foo?

Comment: Possibly. Things to keep in mind is `REMOTE_ADDR` can be spoofed. It can also be changed for legit reasons (like ISP providing a dynamic ip to user) or not-so-legit reasons (using proxies). Identifying a user based on his IP is at best a very weak attempt. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4262098/4882134) for a simple implementation on finding the client ip.

Answer (score 0):

IP is a way like you said, I would recommend to use Cookies. Once the user has completed the experience, you could have a cookie/flag, so when you server read this flag, it would redirect the user whenever you want.

It's browser specific but I still find it the best solution.

Comment: Do you have some pointers to how I can implement this? Is it like a session check for logins?

Comment: Well, it dependes on the language you are using on server side. For instance, if you use PHP, here an example:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp
Session is something different. It's like memory on the server side, each user has exclusively access to it (it is not shared).
Cache is something else. It's like memory on the server side, but it's shared, accessible by all users.
Cookies exist in the client side, in the browser.

Comment: Ah i see. I tried the code as w3 and it didn't recognize the cookie when I went to a different site. It seems like that isn't possible when I looked in to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **_$*SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]*** to fetch visitor ip

then save their ip using ***fwrite()***.

then use ***strpos()*** to match the saved ip with the current visitor ip.

you can use ***file_get_contents()*** anywhere even on different sites.

***in a way :***

```
file_get_contents('http://website/filename.txt');//use this on different site.
```

***The code is like this :***

```
<?php
$clien = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; //Get Visitor Ip

$var = "$clien - "; //add a separator so it doesn't get messy

$fp = fopen('filename.txt', 'a');//opens file in append mode

$file = file_get_contents('filename.txt'); //Get the saved ip

if(strpos($file, $clien) !==false){  //if visitor ip match with the saved ip
//Enable header below if you wanna redirect current visitor 
//header( "Refresh:3; url=http://www.example.com/page2.php");
    echo"You are Cant acces this page";
} else { //if Ip not found
    
        $_SESSION["sesi"] = $clien;

    echo"You are New visitor";
    fwrite($fp, $var);// Save visitor ip
}
```

***Note: visitors can trick this by using vpn***

Answer (score 0):

Cookies don't work that well anymore across websites, and IPs changes all the time.

If you're building a toy project, maybe either of the solutions is 'good enough', but if you're doing something that needs to work reliably, you should probably build a central site that a user gets redirected to, and then redirected back with a code (similar to single sign-on systems of OAuth2).

Fully going into 'how' to build that is a bit outside of the scope of Stack Overflow I think, but this would be my general approach.

Comment: Ah good to know. While the 'good enough' solution is not ideal, it is mostly as a deterrent so I think it would be adequate for now. I imagine the majority of people would not revisit it anyway.